# Can we edit/add options in Application settings page in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application where I want to insert an option in the "Application setting" of the device. Is it possible to edit/add options in Application settings page in native device?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-building-application-preference-screens/

Comment: Which type of option? can you clarify your question a bit more

Comment: I think it's only possible if you create your own ROM.

Comment: but it throws a getActivity Error

Comment: I need to add the login authentication to the application and want to add this option in the application setting menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this [tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) from Sai Geetha. It explain the usage of shared preferences for an android application.